# Creating List of Notation

Tags: table-of-contents

I have been using `LaTeX` for a while however I am new to writing a new command. Essentially I wanted to make a list of notation for my thesis. I have seen quite a few styles of nomenclatures, but none of them really meets my desire.

In my list of notation I want to have one column for the symbols and one column for the corresponding page numbers. Also I want the list of notation to appear in my table of contents. I have roughly had the algorithm:

1. for each symbol, write a new command to assign a label, and keep them in a certain list;
2. write another new command to add list of notation to table of contents, and print these symbols as well as their page numbers.

Apologize if the question is too simple. Maybe there are some packages available but I didn't know. I guess it is not too hard to write a new command for this but I just really haven't learnt any thing about this. So if you can provide me a `MWE` it would be great.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: This could possibly achieved using the `imakeidx` package, `\index[notationindex]{\(\Omega\)} by faking your 'symbol' list to be an index and print it with `\printindex[notationindex]` at the place you desire. Please have a look on `imakeidx`. Perhaps user egreg knows more ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: "Perhaps"? :-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thanks for your suggestion, but in comparison to your way, is it easier that just simply make a table typing $\Omega$ & \pageref{label of $\Omega$}? I am looking for some command which would automatically generate an entry in the table when you type, say \symb{$\Omega$}.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Yes, "perhaps!" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This sets up a quick and dirty list of symbols, using the `\SymbolPrint` command, which either typesets the symbol where it appears and automatically adds an index entry to the `imakeidx` style of splitted indices.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}

\newrobustcmd{\SymbolPrint}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}\index[notationlist]{\ensuremath{#1}}}%



\makeindex[intoc=true,name=notationlist,columns=1,title={List of Symbols}]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First sophisticated chapter}

This is some mathematical text, with the \[\SymbolPrint{\Omega} = 0.5 \cdot \left({\SymbolPrint{\Omega} + \SymbolPrint{\Omega}}\right)\] 
printed in text.
\newpage
Here is another Symbol, \SymbolPrint{\nabla}. And here the famous \SymbolPrint{\Omega} again. 
\newpage
And in an aligned environment
\begin{align*}
  \SymbolPrint{\vec{\nabla}} \circ \vec{v} &= \SymbolPrint{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}} v_{x} + \ldots
\end{align*}
\printindex[notationlist]

\end{document}
```

Of course, the output must be formatted more nicely using a different style, I try to find a solution ;-)
[image]

Comment: Hupefer, I just copied and compiled your codes, but list of symbols didn't show up. Do you know why? It kept warning me to run pdflatex again. I did but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you run `makeindex yourfilename` after the first `pdflatex` run?

Comment: Yes, I did, but nothing changed. Do I need any extra package? The message I got was "Remember to run (pdf)latex again after calling (imakeidx)'splitindex' and processing the indices."

Comment: No, I specified all packages in my solution. Did run it with `pdflatex --shell-escape` ?

Comment: @Easy: The `imakeidx` tries to automatically run the `makeindex` program while `pdflatex` works on your document, so that do not have to do it yourself. In order to make this work, you have to use it in the `pdflatex --shell-escape` - way, enabling a possibility to spawn a subshell (say a method allowing programs to call other programs from within). If you work on Linux, this should be a problem, I do not know how it works on Windows or Mac

Comment: Sorry, I was typing too fast: It should be **no** problem

Comment: Is there somewhere I should enable "shell-escape"? I am using Kile.

Comment: Try `pdflatex yourfile ; makeindex yourfile ; splitindex yourfile ; pdflatex yourfile`, all without extensions, all in a row with `;` on command line

Comment: I never used `Kile`

Comment: Just tried, still nothing changed.

Comment: So what do you use?

Comment: Do you have the latest (possible) Tex Distribution?

Comment: I did exactly what I wrote in my 'commandline' comment ... I always compile that way, because I distaste TeX IDEs

Comment: I am using the newest version. What causes the distaste?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14728/discussion-between-christian-hupfer-and-easy).